# Insertar salto de línea en un Ex.Window en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas, estoy usando JavaScript y he creado una ventana donde se debería mostrar una línea de texto y debajo otra línea de texto junto a su campo fecha, el problema es que al insertar las líneas estas salen seguidas, y no se como evitar esto, el código es similar al siguiente:

```
VentanaCambiarFecha = new Ext.Window({
   title : Cambio de fecha,
   closable : false,
   closeAction : 'hide',
   width : 400,
   height : 250,
   style : 'font-size:15px',
   modal : true,
   items : [{
           xtype : 'label',
           text : 'Se va a copiar el enlace',
           style : 'font-size:13px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left: 20px;'
           }, {
           xtype : 'label',
           text : 'Fecha de caducidad: ',
           style : 'font-size:13px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left: 20px;'
           }, funcionDeFecha],
    buttons : ..........
    ................................................
```

Comment: No tengo aqui para probar pero tal vez si en los styles colocas display: block; lo soluciones

Comment: Muchas gracias, con eso ahora si hay salto de linea, el único problema es que ahora el campo fecha se muestra abajo y el icono del calendario un poco encima de dicho campo, es muy extraño, gracias otra vez Hernán

Comment: No se bien como seria la disposicion de los elementos pero didpkay: block hace que el elemento tome todo el ancho agregando saltos de linea al principio y al fin. Tienes tambien display: inline-block en lugar de block que agrega salto de linea al principio pero no al fin

Comment: De todos modos creo q si solo le pones display block al primero causara el efecto esperado